# Phrase for a person in town known for being insane?

Tags: phrase-requests, phrases, expressions, phrase-usage

This is my first post, forgive me if it is unorthodox. So, I’m looking to title a video, and this is bothering me:

I could’ve sworn there was a phrase to describe a local crazy person in a town or village that is known for having wild beliefs, fears that stand out from the rest of their people, or who has gone mad. (I’m picturing an older person.)

Upon Googling, the phrase “villiage crazy lady” as quoted from the Moana movie comes up, as well as Reddit pages discussing dealings with “local crazy persons/people.”

The phrase that came to my mind was **the town crazy**, sort of like the phrase *town crier* or *village idiot* but those don’t seem right, and now I’m no longer convinced that “the town crazy” is a phrase that is real or will be recognized. Can someone pinpoint the phrase (or word) I am looking for, to, once again, describe a local person known for being unhinged or telling tales of warning that nobody seems to listen to. I’m pretty sure it’s a thing…

Comment: Interesting ngram results: `She was the town *` =>  [tramp, whore, librarian].  `He was the town *` => [drunk, marshal, hero, clerk, doctor, blacksmith, fool, blackguard, crier].

Comment: 'The town madman' gets a few hits, 'the town's madman' more. but 'the town crazy' more still. //  I'm close-voting not because I think the question itself does not have merits, but because  I believe answers will continue to be subjective suggestions rather than commonly used expressions.

Comment: Who wouldn't get "the town crazy"?

Comment: A Google Books search for "[**the town crackpot**](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22the+town+crackpot%22&lr=lang_en&sca_esv=99dc5775480ade1c&tbs=lr%3Alang_1en&tbm=bks&ei=qre5ZbGyDdis0PEPsaCFuAc&ved=0ahUKEwixr4SW0YaEAxVYFjQIHTFQAXcQ4dUDCAk&oq=%22the+town+crackpot%22&gs_lp=Eg1nd3Mtd2l6LWJvb2tzIhMidGhlIHRvd24gY3JhY2twb3QiSABQAFgAcAB4AJABAJgBAKABAKoBALgBDMgBAA&sclient=gws-wiz-books)" yields 13 exact matches (where "crackpot" is a noun and not an adjective modifying a different noun) plus 4 more exact matches for "the town's crackpot." The earliest match is from 1959, and the latest is from 2021.

Comment: [**The term "village idiot" is also used as a stereotype of the mentally disabled**. It has also been applied as an epithet for an unrealistically optimistic or naive individual.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Village_idiot)

Answer (score 3):

Look at synonyms of [“eccentric” on Merriman-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/eccentric).  Go to the “noun” synonyms and you might find what you are looking for.

As the writer, only you can pick the term that will best fit your character.

Ask yourself: Is the character
…an eccentric?
…an oddball?
…a kook?
…a nutcase?
…a crackpot?
…a fruitcake?

Some choices are light-hearted; others are more serious.
Some imply severe mental illness; others imply only unusual behavior.

You could choose a word to convey the true nature of the character in the title. If the character is *truly* crazy and not just perceived that way by onlookers, maybe be straightforward and use the word “insane”.

Or, you may want a title that is sensational and grabs attention - maybe with a word choice describing how the town perceives the character (e.g. “local loon”, “crazy kook”, “town nutcase”, “old eccentric”, etcetera).

Comment: This looks like a [link to an answer](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/313677) (or instruction for finding an answer), rather than an actual answer itself.

Answer (score 2):

I'm partial to alliteration and would go with **[the local lunatic](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the%20local%20lunatic%2Cthe%20town%20crazy&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3)**.

If your video is set in the 1840s, "the town crazy" is a winner.

Here are some books that mention "[the local lunatic](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22the%20local%20lunatic%22%20-asylum%20-asylums%20-institution%20-institutions%20-fringe&newwindow=1&sca_esv=8add31af34f47e86&rlz=1CATMUU_enUS1067&biw=1314&bih=669&tbm=bks&sxsrf=ACQVn08-DceC53syZSaVs9-cyGADeKKpfg%3A1706627653608&ei=RRK5ZYrVJNuiptQPmoim6AQ&ved=0ahUKEwjKi7q4s4WEAxVbkYkEHRqECU0Q4dUDCAk&uact=5&oq=%22the%20local%20lunatic%22%20-asylum%20-asylums%20-institution%20-institutions%20-fringe&gs_lp=Eg1nd3Mtd2l6LWJvb2tzIkcidGhlIGxvY2FsIGx1bmF0aWMiIC1hc3lsdW0gLWFzeWx1bXMgLWluc3RpdHV0aW9uIC1pbnN0aXR1dGlvbnMgLWZyaW5nZUj9HVCzB1jwE3AAeACQAQCYAUSgAYkEqgEBObgBA8gBAPgBAYgGAQ&sclient=gws-wiz-books)". In the search I have tried to exclude local lunatic asylum and local lunatic institution  and their plural forms.

Comment: [Google ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+local+lunatic%2Cthe+town+crazy%2Cpink+monkey&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) would indicate that these are hardly common usages.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth ngram cannot be used to determine the "commonness" and certainly not the aptness of a phrase when it, or its synonyms, are unlikely to appear in print except in rather unusual circumstances. How often is the town crazy or the local lunatic going to be mentioned in print? As for your "pink monkey", https://www.google.com/search?q=%22pink+monkey%22&newwindow=1&sca_esv=8add31af34f47e86&rlz=1CATMUU_enUS1067&tbm=bks&sxsrf=ACQVn095waC0AqDDX50YlSks6HwW9uHVDg:1706627299684&source=lnms&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiBsNiPsoWEAxVymYkEHcpoD7gQ0pQJKAV6BAgCEAg&biw=1314&bih=669&dpr=1

Comment: @EdwinAshworth When the context admits, the phrase appears often enough.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Really? Ngrams for this? If ngrams were the only criterion, writing would already be dead even without the onset (yes, like a disease) of AI. local lunatic and town crazy are both legit possibilities for this **idea**.

Comment: TimR and Lambie. My point. ELU deals with standard usages, idiomatic researchable expressions say; inventions and rare terms may well be fine but do not belong on this site but on say Writing.SE.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth It's a bona-fide phrase request and I've provided the minimal "research" required to show that the phrase has a history.

Comment: A Google search seems to indicate it's an assumed name rather than an established set phrase.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth A name a person has chosen for themselves?  If so, that is not at all supported by the attestations returned when you visit the final link in my answer, which brings up books that use the phrase. It's an established phrase and has been in use for over a century.

Comment: There are less than 3 000 Google hits for "the local lunatic"; most seem references to Jerome K Jerome's phrasing.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth  Did you check out the link at the bottom of my answer, which leads to 19th-21st c. *books* that use  phrase "the local lunatic"?  "Lunatic asylums" was what hospitals for the mentally ill were called until the second half of the 20th century. That was the normal name,  mind you, not a colloquialism. But the term "lunatic" came to be recognized as stigmatizing; clinicians stopped using it, followed by polite society. Nowadays it appears only in fiction, where the author is being *true-to-life*, as many people still continue to use the term *lunatic*.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth But you won't find the term "lunatic" used much on websites, and the people who would use the phrase "the local lunatic" on the internet are likely themselves to qualify for the role.

Comment: Both 'local' and 'lunatic' are fully paid up members of the lexicon. But I'd downvote an answer here suggesting 'yellow eraser' as an answer, however well it fitted a question. It's a free combination, hardly a common usage. And 'local lunatic' may well be likewise.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I don't understand why you're not acknowledging something I've stated three times now: the last link in my answer goes to a list of books dating from the 19th through to the 21st century, where the phrase "the local lunatic" is used in exactly the sense OP is asking for. Googling contemporary websites is not a valid way of determining how common or uncommon the phrase has been for the reasons I cited above having to do with the  cleansing of public discourse of such stigmatizing terms.

Answer (score 1):

When I started reading your question, I thought of "village idiot". However, you say that that's not what you want. Seeing that you want a term for a "local person known for being unhinged or telling tales of warning *that nobody seems to listen to*" (emphasis mine), how about *Cassandra*? [Cassandra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cassandra) was a mythological figure who was blessed with the power of prophecy, but cursed with the fate that nobody believed her.